# TableView scroll issue in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, scrollview, contentoffset

In my application I have a table view which contains collectionview in each row. Its kind of a TV Guide (channels and programs). After launch table I am setting contentOffset for one collection-view to current time so all collection-views in a tableview will scroll.

```
    collectionView.contentOffset= CGPointMake(width*index,0);
```

What ever visible cells of tableview all are working fine. I mean if I select cell, it's giving current time info properly. But if I scrollview the table to the end and select cells, it's giving previous day information.

I mean that there content offset is pointing to zero position so taking old data and not setting to current time. But if scroll horizontally then all cells take showing information properly. How can I achieve this even if I scroll down?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: my only suggestion (since you have not included any description of how you're trying to accomplish what you describe... and only included one line of code that has no context) is to use print debugging to verify that variables contain what you expect at every step.